# Holding data in contenteditable tables

Tags: html, contenteditable

If i have a simple html table, enabling `contenteditable` on the table data. Is it possible to have a formula across the table (for example: cell 1 column 1 + cell 2 column 1 = cell 3 column 1) and from that the `contenteditable` change the variables in the formula and updata the totals?

I was playing a little bit with `contenteditable`:

http://jsfiddle.net/nMhmS/440/

Answer (score 0):

below is simple function which you can use to get the desired results. and here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nMhmS/441/

Plus you can add infinite number of columns and rows and it dynamically put the total in last row

```
function updateTotal(){

    var totalCols=$("#table tr").eq(0).find("td").length-1;
    var toalRows=$("#table tr").length-1;
    var cellValue=0;

    for(var col=0;col<=totalCols; col++){

        for(var row=0;row<=toalRows; row++){

             if(row!=toalRows)            
             cellValue+= parseInt($("#table tr").eq(row).find("td").eq(col).text());

             if(row==toalRows){

                $("#table tr").eq(row).find("td").eq(col).text(cellValue);
                cellValue=0; // reset the Cell Value
             } 

         }

    }          
}
```